# Pandas DataFrame parsing for integers

Tags: python, pandas

This is how my df looks

```
person_a
done 37918 , 37925 to37932 ,37934 to 37939 (17 )

person_b
Done 37940 to 37950 (12 ) and 38101 to 38109 ( 9 )
```

(Couldn't find a good way to show them side by side, person_a and person_b are columns). I need to parse all integers outside the `()` and then include all values including those between `to` into a new dataframe (`video_df`). The number within the `()` are small < 1000 while the outside ones are > 10000

I know I can do extract the numbers outside the `()`

```
video_numbers = df['person_a'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0]
video_df[person_a] = video_numbers[video_numbers.str.len() > 4]
```

but not sure how to expand with `to`

My result should be `video_df`

```
person_a    person_b
37918       37940
37925       37941
37926       .
.           37950
.           38101
37932       .
37934       .
.           38109
.           0
37939       0
```

Fill empty rows with 0. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Not realy sure what you want to do yet, but couldn't you do something with range()  to fill in the 'to' part? e.g. range(37925, 37932 + 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe not so short but i think with some regex and list manipulation it is possible.
first i extracted the numbers from the string for each person

```
df1.replace(to_replace=['\(\d+ \)','\( \d+ \)','Done','done'],value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
df1.replace(to_replace=['to'],value='-', regex=True, inplace=True)
df1.replace(to_replace=['and'],value=',', regex=True, inplace=True)
df1.person_a = df1.person_a.str.split(',')
df1.person_b = df1.person_b.str.split(',')
```

**df1**

```
                                    person_a                             person_b
0  [ 37918 ,  37925 -37932 , 37934 - 37939 ]  [ 37940 - 37950  ,  38101 - 38109 ]
```

---

second step is create df for each person with the ranges

```
person_a = pd.DataFrame(df1['person_a'].values.tolist()).T.rename(columns={0:'person_a'})
person_a = person_a.person_a.str.split('-', expand=True) \
                                .rename(columns={0:'start', 1:'end'}) \
                                .convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) \
                                .fillna(0)

person_b = pd.DataFrame(df1['person_b'].values.tolist()).T.rename(columns={0:'person_b'})
person_b = person_b.person_b.str.split('-', expand=True) \
                                .rename(columns={0:'start', 1:'end'}) \
                                .convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) \
                                .fillna(0)
```

**person_a**

```
   start      end
0  37918      0.0
1  37925  37932.0
2  37934  37939.0
```

**person_b**

```
   start    end
0  37940  37950
1  38101  38109
```

---

final step is define a function to create list of the numbers for each person

```
def ranges(df):
    x = []
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df.end[i] == 0:
            x.append(list(range(int(df.start[i]), int(df.start[i])+1)))
        else:
            x.append(list(range(int(df.start[i]), int(df.end[i])+1)))

    x = [val for sublist in x for val in sublist]
    return x


df = pd.DataFrame({'person_a':pd.Series(ranges(person_a)),'person_b':pd.Series(ranges(person_b))}).fillna(0)
```

---

**df**

```
    person_a  person_b
0    37918.0     37940
1    37925.0     37941
2    37926.0     37942
3    37927.0     37943
4    37928.0     37944
5    37929.0     37945
6    37930.0     37946
7    37931.0     37947
8    37932.0     37948
9    37934.0     37949
10   37935.0     37950
11   37936.0     38101
12   37937.0     38102
13   37938.0     38103
14   37939.0     38104
15       0.0     38105
16       0.0     38106
17       0.0     38107
18       0.0     38108
19       0.0     38109
```